# Converting the Format of Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R so I will be appreciated it if I could have your suggestions.
May I know how to cover my data frame?

Now my data is like this which consists of 3 tests for 3 words coded as "201", "202", and "203".

```
Participant Test    201 202 203
100 Test1   0   0   1
100 Test2   1   1   1
100 Test3   1   0   1
101 Test1   0   0   1
101 Test2   1   0   1
101 Test3   1   1   0
```

May I know how to cover the data frame as beneath (one word ID for one row with tests as columns)?

Thank you.

```
Participant     Word_ID Test 1  Test 2  Test 3
100 201 0   1   1
100 202 0   1   0
100 203 1   1   1
101 201 0   1   1
101 202 0   0   1
101 203 1   1   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Participant = rep(100:101, each=3),
             Test = rep(paste0("Test", 1:3), 2),
             `201` = c(0,1,1,0,1,1),
             `202` = c(0,1,0,0,0,1),
             `203` = c(1,1,1,1,1,0))

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=`201`:`203`, names_to  = "Word_ID") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Test, values_from=value)

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Participant Word_ID Test1 Test2 Test3
        <int> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1         100 201         0     1     1
2         100 202         0     1     0
3         100 203         1     1     1
4         101 201         0     1     1
5         101 202         0     0     1
6         101 203         1     1     0
```